# How to find the angle between surface normal and World Space Z up vector

Tags: normals, vector

I'm trying to use TOA to discover the length denoted in red in the screenshot below but this requires that I find the angle (denoted in green) in rads between the surface normal and the world UP normal which I do not know how to do.

[image]

The calculations will be performed in a material so I'd like it to be as efficient as possible.
How do I go about finding this angle, or is there a better way to find the required length?

Comment: TOA : Time Of Arrival ?

Comment: @StefLAncien TOA in trigonometry stands for **T**angent = **O**pposite / **A**djacent (at least I hope this is meant, and not _tubo-ovarian abscess_).

Comment: Beware that it is quite time consuming to compute an angle with arcsine for example, then to compute the cosine of this angle. If you need cosine, go for the dot product ; if you need sine, go for the cross product; if you need tangent, go for both.

Comment: *"but this requires that I find the angle"* - does it? The length of the red line is simply the distance between the tips of the arrows. I downvoted the question, because you don't mention what is the input data, that is, what information you have. If those arrows are of unit length, simply use Vector Math: Distance, taking the "[true] normal" as first input, and $<0, 0, 1>$ as another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can find the green angle, in shader nodes, by taking the arccosine of the dot product of the world space normal and the world space up vector (which is, I imagine, 0,0,1, but if you're treating some other vector as up, you can use that instead.)  The normal output of a geometry node gives us the surface normal in world space.

[image]

That's displaying the angle, in radians.

The length of the red line depends on its angle to the two vectors-- which is to say, on the length of those vectors.  You may be looking for the length of the line connecting the *unit-length* vectors, which, as StefLAncien offers, is more easily calculated by ignoring the angle, and finding the length of the vector that, added to one vector, reaches the other:

[image]

Or, you may be looking for the length of the vector running through the (unit-length) normal that is orthogonal to the world up vector (or, vice versa, it's the same length.)  It's not necessary to calculate the angle to do so; we can use the dot product directly to calculate the length of the projection of one unit-length vector onto the other:

[image]

Or, you could use trig like you're used to.

Comment: Great answer! Thank you and I appreciate the time spent.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming $\vec{e}_Z$ is the unitary world up "normal" and $\vec{n}$ is the unitary surface normal, use the [cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) to get the sine of green angle $\theta$ as:

$\left| \sin{\theta} \right| = \|\vec{e}_Z \times \vec{n} \|$

and use [the dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) to get the cosine as :

$\cos{\theta} = \vec{e}_Z \cdot \vec{n} $

To get the length $L$ between the tip of both vectors, use:

$L = \| \vec{e}_Z - \vec{n} \|$

Comment: Thank you for answering. If I could accept 2 answers I would accept yours as well as Nathan's as they are equally correct.